# Parsing datetimestamps with timezone offset in Go using google.protobuf.Timestamp

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

I am creating a Go application which will use GRPC and protobuf. My RPC service shall take a message containing the type `google.protobuf.Timestamp`, parse it and eventually save it in a database or perform some more operations on it.

I am confused as to what is considered valid input for the type `google.protobuf.Timestamp`. I wish to use the following format for the datetimestamp with the timezone offset.

`2019-02-15T13:00:00+01:00`

Here is the proto file I am using.

```
syntax = "proto3"
package example;
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"

service Tester {
 rpc ParseDateTimeStamp(TSRequest) returns (TSReply) {}
}

message TSRequest {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp dts = 1;
}

message TSReply {
 string message = 1;
}
```

The issue is that when I send a message to the GRPC server containing the datetimestamp. I would expect that the type `*tsbp.Timestamp` for the `2019-02-15T13:00:00+01:00` datetimestamp given to be valid and give me the appropriate seconds from epoch. (After invoking `GetSeconds()` from the timestamp.go)

Invoking `ptypes.TimestampString(ts *tspb.Timestamp)` returns `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` for the example input above.

Does the `google.protobuf.Timestamp` accept datetimestamps with the +- offset?

Or do I have to have the input in a String type and then parse to `time.Time` with `time.Format` instead of using the timestamp variable type in protobuf? If so could you provide an example of this?

Comment: when returning the `TSReply` message - do you want it to include the original timezone offset? If so, your input value of `ptype.Timestamp` does not have the storage of a TZ value, so any offset would need to be included in an extra field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A gRPC message type of [google.protobuf.Timestamp](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto), internally, is just two `int64`'s

```
message Timestamp {
  // Represents seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch
  // 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
  // 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
  int64 seconds = 1;

  // Non-negative fractions of a second at nanosecond resolution. Negative
  // second values with fractions must still have non-negative nanos values
  // that count forward in time. Must be from 0 to 999,999,999
  // inclusive.
  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

So when in this format-type, there is nothing to *parse*.

One typically takes:

- a string format like your `2019-02-15T13:00:00+01:00` and converts to a `time.Time` using `time.Parse`
- then convert the `time.Time` to a `*tspb.Timestamp` using [ptypes.TimestampProto()](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#TimestampProto)

FYI in your cited output, you are seeing a `zero` timestamp (i.e. both seconds and nanos are zero) - hence the `"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"` output.

---

Implementing the flow above:

```
ts, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2019-02-15T13:00:00+01:00")

pbts, err := ptypes.TimestampProto(ts) // ptypes.Timestamp:"seconds:1550232000 "

fmt.Println(ptypes.TimestampString(pbts)) // "2019-02-15T12:00:00Z"
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UABbRDSYb_y)

**Note:** the `ptype.Timestamp` is stripped of any timezone - `Z` so `UTC` time. So if you need to preserve timezone of a `time.Time`, the offset would need to be sent in your gRPC message in addition to your `google.protobuf.Timestamp` message.