# GOLANG json to Protoc with LocalDateTime, not DateTime

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling, protoc

I'm working on a middleware using golang.
I'm consuming a REST-API which returns a Date in form of a LocalDateTime (e.g. "created": "2022-01-09T00:00:00",) and it should get mapped into an protoc message with the data class google/protobuf/timestamp.proto as we don't want to do the converting in the frontend. But apparently the timestamp.proto only supports DateTime with a timezone (so like that "created": "2022-01-09T00:00:00Z...") but as its an external API I'm consuming I cant change their datatype to DateTime. Does anyone know how to find and elegant solution without doing the complete mapping/unmashalling process manually?

That's the protoc message:
google.protobuf.Timestamp created = 7 [json_name = "created"];

That's the unmashaller we're using:
err = protojson.Unmarshal(body, protoMessageClass)

That's the error I'm getting:
ERROR: proto: (line ...): invalid google.protobuf.Timestamp value "2021-12-07T00:00:00""

Comment: Parse your LocalDateTime `2022-01-09T00:00:00` to this format `2022-01-09T00:00:00Z...` . Then do the mapping it will work. Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342875/parsing-datetimestamps-with-timezone-offset-in-go-using-google-protobuf-timestam

Answer (score 0):

First convert the time you receive as a string to a `time.Time` object:

```golang
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05", val)
```

Here `"2006-01-02T15:04:05"` represents the layout you expect.

Then you can use [timestamppb](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#New) built-in function to create a protobuf timestamp from a `time.Time` object:

```golang
tpb := timestamppb.New(t)
```

If you need the opposite, you can use `AsTime` from `timestampb.Timestamp` type and then `format` from `time.Time` object to make a string.